# How to add a space after a comma if it does not exist within the 6th column in a csv file?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Ubuntu 16.04
Bash 4.3.3

I also need a way to add a space after the comma if one does not exist in the 6th column. I had to comment the above line because it placed a space after all commas in the csv file.

**Wrong:** `"This is 6th column,Hey guys,Red White & Blue,I know it,Right On"`

**Perfect:** `"This is 6th column, Hey guys, Red White & Blue, I know it, Right On"`

I could almost see `awk` printing out the 6th column then having `sed` do the rest:

`awk '{ print $6 }' "$feed " | sed -i 's/|/,/g; s/,/, /g; s/,\s\+/, /g'`

This is what I have so far:

```
for feed in *; do
   sed -r -i 's/([^,]{0,10})[^,]*/\1/5' "$feed"
   sed -i '
      s/<b>//g; s/*//g;
      s/\([0-9]\)""/\1inch/g;
#     s/|/,/g; s/,/, /g; s/,\s\+/, /g;
      s/"one","drive"/"onetext","drive"/;
      s/"comments"/"description"/;
      s/"features"/"optiontext"/;
    ' "$feed"
done
```

`s/|/,/g; s/,/, /g; s/,\s\+/, /g;` works but is global and not within a column.

Comment: You want to add a space after a comma if it doesn't exists? The comma has to exists to add a space after it. How does the input file look like? How is it separated? By spaces, so awk can parse it? What is the expected output? @edit och I get it, you want to add a space after a comma it the space does not exists, sry.

Comment: Why not `awk '{ print $6 }' "$feed " | sed 's/, */, /g'`?   What's the `|` doing? And all the other substitutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like all you need is this (using GNU awk for FPAT):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]+\""; OFS=","} {gsub(/, ?/,", ",$6)} 1'
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
1,2,3,4,5,"This is 6th column,Hey guys,Red White & Blue,I know it,Right On",7,8

$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]+\""; OFS=","} {gsub(/, ?/,", ",$6)} 1' file
1,2,3,4,5,"This is 6th column, Hey guys, Red White & Blue, I know it, Right On",7,8
```

It actually looks like your whole shell script including multiple calls to GNU sed could be done far more efficiently in just one call to GNU awk with no need for a surrounding shell loop, e.g. (untested):

```
awk -i inplace '
BEGIN{FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]+\""; OFS=","} 
{
    $0 = gensub(/([^,]{0,10})[^,]*/,"\\1",5)
    $0 = gensub(/([0-9])""/,"\\1inch","g")
    sub(/"one","drive"/,"\"onetext\",\"drive\"")
    sub(/"comments"/,"\"description\"")
    sub(/"features"/,"\"optiontext\"")
    gsub(/, ?/,", ",$6)
}
' *
```

Comment: but, if input contains blank fields `FPAT` will fail right ?

Comment: @oguzismail. No. The first part of the `FPAT` allows empty fields.

Comment: @ed, This worked well with what you have. I'm going to implement it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^,"]*("[^"]*")*/\n&\n/6;h;s/, ?/, /g;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n.*\n(.*)\n.*\n/\2\1/' file
```

Surround the 6th field by newlines. Make a copy of the line. Replace all commas followed by a possible space with a comma followed by a space. Append the original line and using pattern matching replace the amended field discarding the rest of the ameliorated line.